# What does "It's a bloody steal—go for it, governor!" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the book Predictably Irrational, by Dan Ariely, I found the following expression in bold letters:

> In the case of the *Economist*, I may not have known whether the Internet-only subscription at $59 was a better deal than the print-only option at $125. But I certainly knew that the print-and-Internet option for $125 was better than the print-only option at $125. In fact, you could reasonably deduce that in the combination package the Internet subscription is free! **"It's a bloody steal—go for it, governor!"** I could almost hear them shout from the riverbanks of the Thames. And I have to admit, if I had been inclined to subscribe I probably would have taken the package deal myself. (Later, when I tested the offer on a large number of participants, the vast majority preferred the Internet-and-print deal.)

What does "It's a bloody steal—go for it, governor!" mean?

I know "steal" means bargain in this context, but why "governor"? Is this some idiom or some reference to something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the subscription being priced in (presumably US) Dollars, the paragraph also makes reference to

> the riverbanks of the Thames

i.e. a reference to England, probably London.

In which case *"governor"* (or the more colloquial [guv'nor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guv'nor#guv'nor__2)) would be any person with either authority, or leverage over the speaker. In this case, the situation appears to be one of a salesman speaking to a potential customer, so as per @zondo, `sir` would be an appropriate synonym in this context.

Answer (score 2):

[Governor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/governor) in this context is used to mean "sir":

> **a** slang :  one looked upon as governing
>   **b** :  mister, sir —usually used as a term of address

The meaning of the sentence is "It's a great bargain--buy it!"

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! Is "governor" a synonym for "chief"? Can both be used interchangeably here? I've heard chief before but I had never heard governor in this sense up to now.

Comment: @Yay: It could in this case.  I believe it originally was used to refer to one's father.  Since then, it has included just about everybody.  Maybe "mister" would be a closer synonym.

Comment: As a British English speaker, guv'nor and chief are completely interchangeable when used like this. I disagree that mister is a better synonym, and wouldn't expect someone to user 'mister' unless they were a child (and probably in Victorian England). "Boss" is another synonym and is used more frequently than anything else.